# telethon events wont get specific user's events

Tags: python-3.x, events, telegram, telethon

So i've been working on this script for few days now and the script seems to run correctly without getting any errors but the issue is that my point of the script is getting specific user's status changes and instead of that the script prints me everytime ANYONE from my contants changes they're status inculding myself.
Please, does anyone think he can assist me ? I have been stuck on it for too long now and I am really desprate make that script works..

> By the way, I was adding print(client.user_id) just to see if it works and I received the User ID of anyone in my contacts who made some kind of action.

```py
from telethon.tl.types import UserStatusOffline
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import events
from datetime import datetime
import time

### Client Side ###

target = ""
phone = "+"
api_id = 
api_hash = ""
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
if client.is_user_authorized():
    print(f"Session started at : {datetime.now()}")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Logging in to Telegram complete.")
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
print(f"Started listening to {target}'s status...")
time.sleep(2)
target_id = client.get_peer_id(target)
print(f"{target}'s User ID is : {target_id}")
time.sleep(2)

############################################
# First status check to see rather         #
# the user is correctly online or not      #
# once it prints hes correct statement     #
# global value will be changed so it wont  #
# be printed again and again.              #
############################################

first_msg = False
async def first_con():
    if first_msg == False:
        account = await client.get_entity(target)
        if isinstance(account.status, UserStatusOffline):
            print(f"{target} is correctly Offline.")
            first_msg = True
        else:
            print(f"{target} is correctly Online.")
            first_msg = True
    else:
        print("Something went wrong checking correct status.")
        
            
##################EVENTS####################
# Only events thats occurred after script  #
# first run will pop up with prints !      #
# Every event that doesn't come from the   #
# target gets as "event from username"     #
############################################

@client.on(events.UserUpdate())
async def handler(event):
    await first_con()
    time.sleep(2)
    if event.user_id == target_id:
        if event.online:
            print(f"{target} went Online at : {datetime.now()}")
        elif event.recently:
            print(f"{target} was recently online at : {datetime.now()}")
        elif event.typing:
            print(f"{target} typed a message at : {datetime.now()}")
        else:
            print("Sorry there was an error.")
    else:
        #print("Event from non-intersting user.") debugging propuses only
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's zoom in on the code:

```py
@client.on(events.UserUpdate())
async def handler(event):
    x = await client.get_entity(target)
    target_id = x.id
    event.input_user = target_id
    if event.input_user == target_id:
```

Let's tear it apart:

```py
    event.input_user = target_id
    if event.input_user == target_id:
```

Let's give it different names. `event.input_user` will be `foo` and `target_id` will be `bar`:

```py
    foo = bar
    if foo == bar:
```

You just assigned a value to the first variable, and are then comparing the first variable to that same value. Of course, this is always `True`, for any `foo` and `bar` values.

Modifying the `event` is generally a bad idea and I'm not sure what your intention was, but it seems to me that you should be caching the **integer** ID and then comparing that instead of making the call to `get_entity` every time (because `input_user` is a `InputPeerUser` and won't compare with `User`, which is why I guess you tried the weird assign):

```py
target_id = client.get_peer_id(target)


@client.on(events.UserUpdate)
async def handler(event):
    if event.user_id == target_id:
        ...
```

This way only one call is made at most, and you compare integers which is fast. Make sure to check the [documentation on `UserUpdate`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html#userupdate) for more information.

Comment: So I was doing it and you're right the code is much more cleanier than earlier and it replaces the blabla function.
But still for some reasons it wont print anything.
I mean like if im running the script and all works correctly im supposed to get a first print since its checking the user status on first running and the user must have one of those 3 if conditions..
so basically if it works good im supposed to get like
target went offline/online depeneds on hes statement which i dont get

Comment: You should also enable `logging` and first of all make sure the event is called at all (without any weird `if`). Telegram may not be sending the updates in the first place. Although I don't know the rules you probably need to show "interest" in a user to get updates about them.

Comment: Im sorry im still on it and I couldnt find anyway to make it work properly... There is always something else that doesnt work.